# Maximizing sum of concave functions subject to a linear constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The specific problem I have is of the following type.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \frac{1}{1-a}x^{1-a} + \frac{1}{1-b}y^{1-b} +\frac{1}{1-c}z^{1-c}\\ \text{subject to} & x+y+z=K\end{array}$$

where $x,y,z$ are the optimization variables and $a, b, c > 1$ are constants.

I have tried using a Lagrange multiplier but it didn't work.

Is there a way to solve problems of this type? If not, is there a numerical method for approximating?

Comment: $K$ is a positive constant.

Comment: What did you get with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: $x^{-a}=\lambda$;

$y^{-b}=\lambda$;

$z^{-c}=\lambda$;

$x+y+z=K$

Wasn't able to solve for any.

Comment: In that case $x=\lambda^a$ and similarly for $y$ and $z$, so you get $\lambda^a+\lambda^b+\lambda^c=K$, which given specific values of $a,b,c,K$ you can solve numerically for $\lambda$.

Comment: No algebraic solutions possible?

Comment: [Not when $a\ge5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for example

Comment: And even not if one of $a,b,c$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

you will get $$x^{-a}+\lambda=0$$, $$y^{-b}+\lambda=0$$, $$z^{-c}+\lambda=0$$ and $$x+y+z=K$$ solve this system!

Comment: I reached there too. It appears to be solvable when I count the unknowns and equations. But for some reason, it cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Represent x, y, z with $\lambda$ and substitute them into the fourth equation.
2. Then use bisection method to numerically solve for $\lambda$.